# How can I add an X-header to unix mailx?

Tags: email, unix, sendmail

I am attempting to add the x-header X-APP-VOLT: Yes to the header of my email with a .tar attachment.  I only have access to usr/sbin/sendmail and mailx.  I do not have root access so I can't download other versions of mailx or mutt.

I can add the x-header to usr/sbin/sendmail using the below code, but I can't figure out how to add the .tar attachment.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- toemail << END
To: toemail
Subject: Test
X-APP-VOLT: Yes
Hope this works!
END
```

I can attach a .tar file to mailx using the the below code, but I can't figure out how to add a x-header.  My mailx also does not have the -a option.

```
cat file | uuencode filename | mailx -s "Test" toemail
```

Thank you

Comment: Same question cross-posted to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31053337/427158

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe output of multiple command into sendmail input.
If the code below does not work for you the name (command) shell you use.

```
(
# Command 1: "here document with headers and initial body lines
cat << END
To: toemail
Subject: Test
X-APP-VOLT: Yes
Hope this works!

Email Body line 1

END
# Command 2: uuencode file
cat file | uuencode filename
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- toemail
```